# c++ request for member `A' in `B', which is of non-class type `C'

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I get the error message `request for member 'namn' in 'post', which is of non-class type 'telefonbok[10]'`, or similar versions of it.

I think it has to do with the following bit of code:

```
struct telefonbok 
   {
       string namn;
       string nummer;           
   };

int main()
{
int i, ja, nej;
telefonbok post[10];
```

What am I doing wrong? 
The errors are targeted at:

```
cin>>post.namn;
```

and

```
cin>>post.nummer;
```

Here is the full code, sorry about the Swedish:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct telefonbok 
   {
       string namn;
       string nummer;           
   };
int main()
{

int i, ja, nej;
telefonbok post[10];
bool svar; //behövs för frågan om man vill fortsätta.

for (i=0; i<10; i++)
{
         cout<<"Lagg till en post i telefonboken."<<endl;
         cout<<"Ange personens namn"<<endl;
         cin>>post.namn;
         cout<<"Ange personens nummer :"<<endl;
         cin>>post.nummer;
         cout<<"Vill du mata in en post till? (ja/nej)"<<endl;
         cin>>svar;
         if (svar == nej) break; //stoppar slingan om man svarar nej

}

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Thank you for any help that you may be able to provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`post` is an array, so accessing one member you need to do `cin>>post[index].namn;` instead of  `cin>>post.namn;`

You want to access a single `post` element in the array, and a member of that element.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is another stupid question but now the for-loop is broken, the "cin" is like it is not there for when the for-loop is run the 2nd time and 3rd and so on...

Comment: cin>>post[i].nummer;   --- And the same for: cin>>post[i].namn;

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of `telefonbok` objects, you need to specify to which one you want to read the information.

So the lines should read something like:

```
cin >> post[i].namn; //i is an index to the array; the for loop variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cin>>post.namn;
```

`post` is an array. So that should be something like this:

```
cin>>post[i].namn;
```